# Laravel make url accessable

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I've got website on hosting and I want to access the old site.
I have it in directory named old-site
In `Exceptions > Handler.php` file I have the following code:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        return redirect()->route('not-found');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Because I need to pass data to the not-found route.
But when I try to access `mysite.com/old-site` it throws the exception, but I want to open the contents within old-site folder. How can I do that?

Comment: you have it in a directory where?

Comment: along the other folders of the laravel root directory
I have `images` folder etc. and folder `old`
But I handled with the problem
I thought the folder was `old-site` but it's actually `old`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the `old-site` directory inside the `public` folder of Laravel.
If  you have the default `.htaccess` file, all the requests made to http://your.site/old-site/some-file.php are not redirected to the default laravel `index.php`, they will bypass the framework.
I just made a try and it works